# Canvas device orientation scaling

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I made a racetrack game. I am trying to make it scalable on mobile devices.

I was able to make it look fine when device orientation is normal (vertical):

[image: ![enter image description here]

But when I rotate the device to horizontal view, this happens: (how to zoom it out a bit )?

[image]

What would you recommend doing? I used `display: none`  to hide the images.
I would really appreciate any help.

Edit: I've managed to do this but the view is still too much zoomed, any ideas?

```js
const width = 800;
const height = 600;
const pixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
canvas.width = width * pixelRatio;
canvas.height = height * pixelRatio;

canvas.style.width = `${width}px`;
canvas.style.height = `${height}px`;

// for sprites scaled up to retina resolution
canvas.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
canvas.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;

c.scale(pixelRatio, pixelRatio);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height">

    <!-- <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> -->
    <title>Canvas Story</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        canvas {

            display: block;
        }
        body {
            margin: 0;
        } 
        #container {
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 800px;
            height: 600px;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
            border: 1px solid #000;
            border-radius: 10px;
            margin-top: 2px;
        } 
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <br/>
    
    <img id="obstacle" src="obstacle.png" style="display: none;" />
        <img id="bonus" src="bonus.png" style="display: none;" />
        <img id="bullet" src="bullet.png" style="display: none;" />
        <img id="car" src="car.png" style="display: none;" />

    <div id="container">
        <canvas id="ltpcanvas"></canvas>
    </div>

    <div class="circleBase" id="rotateMode" style="margin:0 auto;">
        <button id="left" onmousedown="leftKeyPressed()" onmouseup="leftKeyReleased()" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span></button>
        <button id="right" onmousedown="rightKeyPressed()" onmouseup="rightKeyReleased()" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span></button>
        <button id="middle" onclick="bulletsPush()" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-record"></span></button>
        <button id="up" onmousedown="upKeyPressed()" onmouseup="upKeyReleased()" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span></button>
        <button id="down" onmousedown="downKeyPressed()" onmouseup="downKeyReleased()" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span></button>
    </div>
    
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="canvas.js"></script>

    

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: take a look here: https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-resizing-the-canvas.html. It doesn't matter if the explanation is for WebGL. The concept is the same.

Comment: From the second picture it seems like the upper part of your raceway is out of the visible area of the browser - so how are you resizing the container div / canvas on device rotation? It doesn't show up in the code you've posted.

Answer (score 1):

use this in head tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

The width=device-width part sets the width of the page to follow the screen-width of the device (which will vary depending on the device).

The initial-scale=1.0 part sets the initial zoom level when the page is first loaded by the browser.

and
in animate add these:

```
            c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            drawCanvas(boundaryLeftOffset - 2, 0,window.innerWidth, 
            window.innerHeight, 'grey');
```

Comment: I tried edited version but doesn't seem to work either. Maybe it's because of my CSS ? I have canvas inside div. I appreciate that you are trying to help me.

Comment: @Simonsoft177 I took whole of your code and run it on my computer . Its not even running in big screen .

Comment: try to reinitialize in your canvas and do.Once I drawed a bar chart from chart.js , I reinitialised it It worked but I dont have the code now  and I dont learn codes

Comment: what do you mean by reinitializing canvas?. Clear canvas? But where exactly?

Comment: It doesn't :( It's like when i shrink down the Web explorer window the canvas cant fit and it's deformed

Comment: use this  https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/responsive.html

Answer (score 1):

Update `canvas` size or anything you need, in a callback for `resize` events of the `window` object:

```js
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    // canvas resize, etc.
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

if `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` doesnt work then you might want to look into the @media query. Its helped me a lot in the past and I think it will help you especially if you know the resolution of the monitors/screens.

Comment: I know what you are trying to say but I don't know the source of this problem. What to change size of when resolution lower, because my canvas suppouse to be 800x600

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the size of the canvas based on the size of the viewport (and be sure to do this if the viewport size changes (E.g. by rotating screen):

```
// Set canvas size (how many 'pixels' are on the canvas)
// NOTE CSS determines how large the canvas is, this determines
// the size of the things you draw on it.
const width = 800;
const height = 600;
const canvasAspectRatio = width / height;

// Also define the gap we want at the edges:
const edgeMargin = 10;

// Set the number of 'pixels' in the canvas.
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;

// Sets the canvas size based on the window height and width
function setCanvasElementSize () {
  const windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
  const windowHeight = window.innerHeight;

  // Work out the orientation of the device.
  const isPortrait = window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth;

  if (isPortrait) {
    // We want to constrain the canvas by its width
    canvas.style.width = windowWidth - (2 * edgeMargin);
    // The height depends on the width to ensure we don't stretch pixels
    // on the canvas.
    canvas.style.height = canvas.style.width / canvasAspectRatio;
  } else {
    // constrain by height
    canvas.style.height = windowHeight - (2 * edgeMargin);
    canvas.style.width = canvas.style.height * canvasAspectRatio;
  }
}

// Call the function once initially to size the canvas
setCanvasElementSize();

// Also add a resize listener so we can ensure the canvas is 
// adjusted when the screen rotates.

// BONUS: Only do this once per animation frame.
let rafRequest = null;
window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
  if (rafRequest) {
    clearAnimationFrame(animationFrameReference);
  }

  let rafRequest = requestAnimationFrame(function () {
    rafRequest = null;
    setCanvasElementSize();
  });
});
```

**CAVEATS:**

1. I haven't tested this code, there may be typos!
2. Some mobile browsers behave differently to others when it comes to measuring the window size. For example, some do not take into account the size of the address bar, or whether or not the keyboard is visible. This is kind of beyond the scope of the question though. If you want to adjust for this you'll have to do some more extensive testing/research then increment or decrement the size of the canvas in `setCanvasElementSize()` accordingly.